# Json extractor error al filtrar por un campo en JMeter

Tags: json, filtro, jmeter

Tengo un problema y es que estoy intentando hacer una extraccion en json extractor de jmeter y le paso una sentencia de json extractor normal

```
 ($.trips[0].journeysAvailable[*].fares[?(@.productClass=='BA')]..fareSellKey)
```

pero tengo que hacer un filtro con una sentencia:

```
 [?(@.productClass=='BA')]
```

y al ejecutar el debugger me sale que no encuentra nada.

Alguna idea del porque no me funciona cuando si voy a una pagina de json path si que me va?

Comment: ¿Podrías enviar un ejemplo JSON Responcse?

Comment: Ahora mismo no tengo ningun response porque al final lo hice con JSR223 y con Javascript, la cosa es que no me salia error ni nada, unicamente que en el debugguer me salia en blanco o con el mensaje personalizado. Ya digo funcionar no me ha funcionado pero por Javascript sí.